# java messaging - how to create an ad-hoc network

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I have 3 clients. I would like to create an application that shows when each client is online and when not based on the JMS - java messaging and tomcat server. Till now I successfully succeed to create a sending and receiving messaging using JMS (queue1).

I don't know from where to start in order to make my application alive.

Thank you.
Need help.
Appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, JMS is quite a heavy-weight way to implement this behaviour.  You'd be far better off using a [MulticastSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html).

However the basic principle is the same whichever route you take:

1. each client sends a heartbeat messages identifying itself at predefined intervals until it is closed or dies.
2. the monitoring application listens for those heartbeat messages, keeps track of the clients that have identified themselves in the heartbeat messages and assumes a client is dead when the heartbeat messages stop for a given client.

With JMS these messages would be sent to a single queue, with a [MulticastSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) you send a [DatagramPacket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) to a group.

Comment: don't i need to use topics too? is there a way of broadcasting a clients message to other clients? can you please send me some example models? need some help! appreciate! Instead of multicastsockets can't I use queues?

Comment: With JMS, if you need to broadcast the heartbeats because you want the clients to speak to one another or there's more than one monitor application you'll need to use a topic (though from the perspective of the code receiving or posting the messages they're all JMS destinations).  This looks like an example that should at least get you moving in the right direction - http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2002/jw-0315-heart.html